# Escape a ! in the password parameter of wget

Tags: bash, wget

I'm trying to execute something like this:

```
wget --user=foo --password=bar! url
```

The ! in the password is causing problems.  I've tried escaping it with \, as in

```
--password=bar\!
```

I've tried encapsulating in single and double quotes.  I put the password in a separate file and tried

--password=`cat pass.txt`

Each time, I get a 403 Forbidden.  Using -d, I see that the SSL handshake is successful.  On the Windows command line, the command works.  My assumption is that I need to escape the ! differently, but I don't know how else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using quotes:

`--password="bar\!"` or `--password='bar\!'`

What is the error on the server side?

**Update:**
I ran a test on my Ubuntu 10.4 machine running Apache 2.2.14. `wget --user=foo --password=bar! url` works for me.

If I use the wrong password, I get an error like `user foo: authentication failure for "/directorytest/": Password Mismatch`.

**Update again: (Taking a step back)**

You say this error is "client denied by server configuration". I browsed the Apache source, and this error message comes from [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html). This indicates that your problem is not with the password (Which is authentication) but your client host is not authorized to access this Apache resource. mod_authz_host deals with hostnames and IPs.

Above, you say "On the Windows command line, the command works." Are all of your tests coming from the same client system? Are you running 'wget' on this same Windows system? What happens if you try to access this same URL using IE or Firefox?

More discussion [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/httpd-client-denied-by-server-configuration/) and [here](http://damonparker.org/blog/2007/01/06/apache-error-client-denied-by-server-configuration/).

Comment: Negatory on both.

error_log:
`client denied by server configuration`

Comment: Looks like you're right Stefan.  mod_authz_host is included, and the vhost conf has Deny All, then has specific allows.  Odd that we have it set to deny access from self.

Comment: I prefer `'` as it escapes other special characters such as `$`

Answer (score 0):

Try `%21`, which is the URL-encoded value of `!`.

Comment: -wget -d --user=foo --password=bar%21 url

Still 403's

Answer (score 0):

Try `set +H` to turn off Bash's history expansion.

**Edit:**

Try setting `password = STRING`, `http_password = STRING` or `ftp_password = STRING` in your `~/.wgetrc` file or a file pointed to by the `WGETRC` environment variable and omitting the `--password` option from the command line.

Comment: Tried that with and without escaping the !.  Neither worked.

Comment: @Dave: See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't work:

`wget ftp://user:p!w@url.com/file`

You can use:

`wget ftp://user:p\!w@url.com/file`

Please note the '\' before '!'

Comment: those are identical?

Comment: It was an error in markup that made them look similar; it's fixed now. @user174154: use the "code" markup for things like this, i.e. the curly braces.