# How to escape ! in password?

Tags: linux, mysql, bash

How might one escape the exclamation point in a password:

```
$ mysql -umyuser -pone_@&!two
-bash: !two: event not found
```

Trying the obvious backslash did not help:

```
$ mysql -umyuser -pone_@&\!two
[1] 22242
-bash: !two: command not found
name@domain.com [~]# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

All my google searches suggest that the backslash would help, but it does not. There is no way to use quotes as suggested in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/150282/escape-a-in-the-password-parameter-of-wget?rq=1). The line will be used in a .bashrc alias. Don't worry, the usernames and passwords shown here are examples only and not used in production!

Comment: you can always use single quotes.  to use a single-quote "inside" a single-quoted string, try: `''\'`

Comment: BTW, putting the password on the command line is a potential security risk on a multi-user system.  It is trivially easy to examine the command-line args of any running process.  Use a .my.cnf file instead (remember to `chmod 600` it).

Comment: oops.  that's `'\''`, not `''\'`

Comment: Thanks, Craig. Actually, this is more secure than the alternative: emailing everyone a copy of the password which will then be store who-knows-where. I personally would prefer that each dev has his own `/home/user` and mysql user, but I'm not the decision maker in that regard.

Comment: management is wise and all-knowing :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use single quotes around the password like this: `-p'one_@&!two'`

To put it in an alias, you'd do something like:

`alias runmysql='mysql -umyuser -p'\''one_@&!two'\'''`

Comment: no space between the -p and password, but yes, this should work

Comment: already edited out the space :)

Answer (score 5):

```
-bash: !two: command not found
```

You also need to escape the `&` character:

```
$ mysql -umyuser -pone_@\&\!two
```

Comment: Yes, because the `&` character is meant for putting a process into background.

Answer (score 5):

If you never use the ! history features, it might be more convenient to simply disable them (with `set +H` in your bashrc).

Answer (score 3):

You can store the password in a bash variable:

```
$ pass='one_@&!two'
```

Then substitute the variable in the command:

```
$ mysql -umyuser -p$pass
```

Comment: interesting answer ;)